# Does the Telekinetic feat also increase the distance you can move the mage hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, magic

The Telekinetic feat from Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything says the following:

> You learn the *mage hand* cantrip.... if you already know this spell, it’s range increase by 30 feet when you cast it.

Mage Hand has a range of 30 feet, and says the following:

> The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 feet away from you or if you cast this spell again.

Does this mean that even though the range for Mage Hand is now 60 feet, if you cast it beyond 30 feet, it still disappears?

 Also, Mage Hand says the following:

> You can move the hand up to 30 feet each time you use it.

Can you still only move it 30 feet? Or can you move it 60?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### RAW: You can cast it up to 60 feet but if you cast it more than 30 feet away it instantly disappears

From the rules on [Range](http://Once%20a%20spell%20is%20cast,%20its%20effects%20aren%27t%20limited%20by%20its%20range,%20unless%20the%20spell%27s%20description%20says%20otherwise.):

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell's description says otherwise.

So, you can cast the *Mage Hand* at a point within 60 feet - the increased Range from the *Telekinetic* feat. It is then not limited by range "unless the spell's description says otherwise." Which it does: "The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 feet away from you".

### This is clearly not what is intended

Obviously. Because if this is what is intended then the feature does nothing and, if so, you might as well save the drafting, proofreading and ink used in writing it.

I think the intention is that the 30 feet limit after casting should be increased to 60 feet to match the Range because I suspect that the drafter and proofreader thought that Range meant both things when it actually doesn't.

You are still limited to moving the hand 30 feet per turn.

Comment: This book seems to be full to the brim with laughable oversights.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Well, its a WotC book - what did you expect? Proof reading is something that happens in other publishers' books.