# Does knowing the Mage Hand cantrip before getting Telekinetic extend your shove range as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

The [Telekinetic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/telekinetic) feat from *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything* (p. 81) has this benefit:

> You learn the *mage hand* cantrip. [...] If you already know this spell, its range increases by 30 feet when you cast it. [...]

It also says you can use it to shove creatures within 30 feet of you:

> As a bonus action, you can try to telekinetically shove one creature you can see within 30 feet of you.

Another question here already asks [Does the Telekinetic feat also increase the distance you can move the mage hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178908/does-the-telekinetic-feat-also-increase-the-distance-you-can-move-the-mage-hand) – but does the same logic apply to the shove range as well?

In other words: If you're already benefiting from a 60-foot range, and assuming you agree that it doesn't vanish if more than 30 feet away, can you use the hand to shove a creature 5 feet so long as it's no more than 60 feet away from you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Telekinetic only extends the range of *mage hand*

The Telekinetic feat grants you three independent abilities:

> - Increase your Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma score (...)
> - You learn the *mage hand* cantrip. (...) If you al­ready know this spell, its range increases by 30 feet (...)
> - As a bonus action, you can try to telekinetically shove one creature you can see within 30 feet of
>   you. (...)

The ability to shove is a separate, independent ability from the mage hand ability and its extended range. It does not have anything to do with *mage hand*, and it is explicitly limited to 30 feet. This ability does not state that it extends to 60 feet when you already have *mage hand* before you take the feat, so it won't.

You can see that the individual bullet points of a feat are independent from each other unless they explicitly state otherwise from [this answer on Crossbow Expert in the Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA082):

> **Is it intentional that the second benefit of Crossbow Expert helps ranged spell attacks?** Yes, it’s intentional. (...) The second benefit of Crossbow Expert prevents you from suffering (...) disadvantage, whether or not the ranged attack is with a crossbow.

As for the related question, the *range* of a spell is a special attribute of the spell, distinct from other distances mentioned in the spell's text. Telekinetic interacts only with the range, not with any other distances mentioned. This is explained in detail in this [excellent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177342/can-the-spell-booming-blade-be-affected-by-the-twinned-spell-metamagic/177345#177345) by Thomas.

If you already have mage hand, allowing you to also extend the distance for shove or other distances mentioned within the text of *mage hand* would likely not be overpowered from a game balance perspective. The rules are there to serve you to have fun, so if both you and your DM agree this makes more sense for the feat, you are free to make a ruling and change this.

Comment: Does that mean you don't agree with the answer on the other question?

Comment: It also says "This is clearly not what is intended" and "I think the intention is that the 30 feet limit after casting should be increased to 60 feet to match the Range"

Comment: We normally answer questions about what the rules say, and do not speculate on what they intended. If you would *like* to apply the exteneded distance also to shove, and your DM is fine with it, I do not think it would be overpowered, and they can just overrule the rules by what they think makes more sense. I'll add that.

Comment: I had to check  with somebody in chat, (possibly because I had skimmed your later edits and got distracted by what you added later on) that not only is the the shove *range*  *completely* separate from mage hand **spell range** (i.e. I knew it doesn't say 'within the range of the Mage Hand spell'), but **entirely separate from casting the spell at all** (which on a second reading you do say).